# Delete files from the database

Tags: vb.net, delete-row

I need to delete data from the database and only the selected row will be deleted using VB data grid view.
I can only delete the data in the data grid view, but how do I delete it in the database itself?

I'm using an MS Access database.

```
Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click

If MessageBox.Show("Do you want to delete this row ?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = DialogResult.Yes Then

        If ProfilesDataGridView.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then

            For i As Integer = ProfilesDataGridView.SelectedRows.Count - 1 To 0

                ProfilesDataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(ProfilesDataGridView.SelectedRows(i).Index)
            Next
        Else
            MsgBox("No rows to select!")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Adding the vb.net tag, but I'm not sure that it's not vb6 or vba instead.

Comment: If you can fetch data from database, then you're already on the way of solving it yourself. What have you tried hitherto ? I see no attempt in your code to delete anything from the database...

Comment: i just use Me.ProfilesTableAdapter1.Fill(ProfilesDataSet.Profiles) to populate my data grid view  because the code only deletes the data in the data grid view but not permanently it just came back where i restart the program
sorry im just created this account so i dont know how this sites works

Comment: @Dukeling - must be vb.net as there is a `MessageBox.Show` in there

Comment: i dont know whats the difference though but im using visual studio 2013 ultimate